# how can I use javascript to clear an input file preview img tag when the submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

The snippet below runs into an error on the function call, but in my own code it runs and the img gets a src of an ObjectURL like http://127.0.0.1:5500/8ad5a92b-bf60 for example.

Then, once I'm done with uploading the file (code not present in snippet) I want to clear the img preview, so I use URL.revokeObjectURL() to release the Object URL and then I set the preview img src to "". Which DOES get rid of the image, but only replaces it with a non-displaying image icon via alt = "your image".

Is there some way for me to actually reset the  tag to it's default state before input's onchanged was triggered?

```js
function clearPreview(){
      var preview = document.getElementById("previewImage").src;
      URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
      document.getElementById("previewImage").src = "";
}
```

```html
<img id="previewImage" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" />

<input type="file" 
    onchange="document.getElementById('previewImage').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
    
 <button type="button" onclick="clearPreview()">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: maybe the error in the snippet is caused by typo. note `previewImage` and `previewImg`

Comment: @lastr2d2 No, sorry- that was just me doing a shoddy job of making sure everything was correct. I didn't copy paste from my own code, re-typed since it was just a few lines.

Comment: Why don't you clear the `alt` after a submit and add it back on input change?

Comment: I edited your question so the IDs match, and the preview is exactly the same from first render to after selecting an image and clicking submit?
Are you sure it wasn't just the typo? What exact result are you lookin for?